# Problem computing population quantiles with survey micro data

Tags: quantiles, extreme-value, survey-weights, survey-sampling, fat-tails

All the major federal surveys come (American Community Survey, Current Population Survey, others) come with survey weights, such that the individual household observations times the population weights is approximate representative of the population as a whole.

I would like to use survey data like this to estimate income quantiles, presumably by summing the person weights of the households with incomes below some incomee level, and dividing by the total of all person weights.

But there is aa problem with this approach. These surveys take a sample of the population -- they are surveys, not censuses. So the highest individual in the sample will only very rarely be, or be nearly, the highest income individual in the population. So it seems that when computing quantiles for any income level, some allowance would need to be made for the population share of those with incomes above the maximum income reported in the micro data.

How might one compute this population share? Some kind of extreme value theory, maybe?

Comment: I am not aware of any serious interface of extreme value theory and survey inference. The former relies on the models of the tails, and on the asymptotics that generally depends on the data being i.i.d. (at least to the extent I understand EVT, which I had last seen ~15 years ago). Survey inference is never i.i.d., and is generally distrustful of models. For mid-range quantiles, the approaches have existed since Woodruff (1952) -- see DOI: 10.1016/S0167-7152(00)00207-8. See also [Shao (1994)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2242300) as the central reference.